# Restoring firmware without Apple Configurator? (MacBook Pro 2019 13")

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel-panic, apple-configurator

I have a MacBook Pro 13" 2019. It won't install any macOS version on it. Running an Ventura install disk gives the error: `Software update required to run this disk.` I have another MacBook, but it's too old to connect to my new MacBook (it's an 13" Pro model from 2014, maybe there is a way? Patched Monterey installation maybe?).

Apple Configurator isn't an option, unfortunately. I thought maybe there is some sort of command or program to fix the firmware? I can launch macOS on an external drive.

I am desperate.

PS: Before the drive was wiped, I got the error: "**Panic Medic Boot**" maybe this helps someone to know what the problem is?

Comment: "Panic Medic Boot" was a crashed 3rd party extension, which the OS should have automatically disabled for you. Why did you go straight to clean install? What happens if you use Internet Recovery, starting from Cmd/Shift/Opt/R specifically? [which should offer the OS your Mac was first shipped with] The Configurator trick is for M1 Macs.

Comment: @Tetsujin When I try internet recovery, while going through options, it randomly shuts off

Comment: Then you may have a hardware issue. I'd take it to an authorised repairer, to check.

Comment: @Tetsujin Unfortunate, because using external disk works fine

Comment: Then all I can say is… 'we don't have sufficient information to diagnose further'.

Comment: @Tetsujin I understand, thanks for the help anyways :)